Why do some limits are not apparent on their graph/plot?
As we know that limiting value of a function can be determined by its graph, may be, I consider this function it is
$$f(x)=\frac{x-\log(1+x)}{x^2} $$
here when $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=1/2$
one can calculate by any method but the problem is that from its graph how can we conclude this from its graph as it seems to be approaching $-\infty$ and $\infty$ as $x\to 0$ not $1/2.$

What are you using to graph the function? With WolframAlpha, I don't see the behavior you're describing.

DMcMor, the base of the logarithm has to be the Euler's number $e$. Look at the graph of the function $f(x),.;$

The problem might be the base of the logarithm.  With $\log_{10}$ (which is the default logarithm in some graphing software, like Desmos) we get the behavior you describe.  Try typing $\ln$, rather than log, in your graphing software -- you should get the behavior you expected.
